# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Setup is Blocked

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to install SQL server Management studio for windows 10 
It gives an error stating that something has blocked set up from continuing..

I tried Opening my command prompt as administrator, and run the following lines but it again gives an error

reg DELETE “HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio” /reg:32

The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value

How do I resolve the problem??

Comment: Are you certain you are an administrator on it? That's the sort of error you get if you aren't. (Also, anything else that might block it? i.e. AV software)

Comment: I am running the command prompt as an administrator ..... and I am an administraor on my machine... I checked it in user accounts